# Ubuntu does not load open source video driver

Tags: 13.04, ati, xorg, radeon, gpu-driver

My notebook uses ATI Radeon HD3650 as the graphical card, and runs ubuntu 13.04 32bit. I use open source video driver for it (radeon), but it seems that this driver is not loaded by ubuntu, then it does not work. I use "lshw -c video" to check the video driver, and the output is here:
[image]

Also I tried "dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'" suggested by ubuntu help document, and the output is here:
[image]

My xorg.conf file is shown here:
[image]

I have tried "dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg", but it does not work. Currently ubuntu in my laptop only supports the resolution with 4:3 ratio, but the actual optimal resolution of the screen is with 16:9 ratio. I am sure that the open source drivers are correctly installed by default, and I do not have any binary drive from ATI in use (actually the ATI driver for my card (catalyst 13.1) does not work with the xserver (1.13) currently used by raring).

Thanks for reading, and I appreciate for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by reinstalling a fresh ubuntu raring. (still do not know the cause though.)